# Re-render sibling on selection or a better?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am kind of new to react & TypeScript.

I am trying to modify some functionality but having hard time doing that.

Currently we show all the subscriptions and all the transactions on the same page instead what I want to do is that based on the subscription selection i want show all the transactions (Currently both subscriptions and transactions are siblings).

I have created an on click event on subscription which is calling `handleViewTransaction`

The problem is that I am not able to re-render `TransactionsTable` from the `handleViewTransaction`.

Do I need to make it parent-child or there is a way to achieve it without much code refactoring?

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {RouteComponentProps} from 'react-router-dom'
import * as _ from 'lodash'
import * as cx from 'classnames'
import {Accordion, AccordionItem} from 'react-light-accordion'
import * as dcbApi from '../../../components/dcbApi'
import {Page} from '../../components/page'
import {Loader} from '../../components/loader'
import {Modal} from '../../components/modal'
import {SubscriptionStore, SubscriptionStoreState, useSubscriptionStore} from '../../../stores/subscription'
import {TransactionsTable} from '../../components/tables/transactions'
import {SubscriptionsTable} from '../../components/tables/subscriptions'
import {TransactionsPage} from './transactions'
import {BokuSubscription, BokuTransaction} from '../../../types'

export interface ResultPageProps extends RouteComponentProps<{}> {
    userId?: string
    subscriptions?: BokuSubscription[]
    transactions?: BokuTransaction[]
    isLoading?: boolean
    onRefetch?: () => any
}

export const ResultPage = ({ isLoading: isLoadingParent, history, userId, subscriptions, transactions, onRefetch }: ResultPageProps) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);
    const [subscriptionCancellationSent, setSubscriptionCancellationSent] = React.useState(false);
    const [transactionCancellationSent, setTransactionCancellationSent] = React.useState(false);
    const [selectedTransaction, setSelectedTransaction] = React.useState(null);
    const hasTransactions = false;
    const navigateHome = () =>
        history.push('/');

    const handleViewTransaction = async (daznUserId: string, subscriptionId: string, aggregator: string) => {
        // TODO: Show subscription specific transactions
    };

    const handleSubsctiptionCancel = async (userId: string, subscriptionId: string) => {
        try {
            setIsLoading(true);
            const response = await dcbApi.cancelSubscription(userId, 'boku', subscriptionId);
            setIsLoading(false);
            setSubscriptionCancellationSent(true);
            Modal.info({
                title: `Your cancellation request has been submited for ${userId}`,
                okText: 'OK',
                content: (
                    <div>
                        <span>Transaction Id:</span> {response.transactionId}<br/>
                        <span>Subscription Id:</span> {response.subscriptionId}<br/>
                        <span>Aggregator:</span> {response.aggregator}<br/>
                        <span>Status:</span> {response.status}<br/>
                    </div>
                ),
            })
            //this.setState({ cancellationSent: true })
        } catch (err) {
            setIsLoading(false);
            console.error(err);
            Modal.info({
                title: `Your cancellation request for ${userId} has failed`,
                okText: 'OK',
                content: (
                    <div>
                        {_.get(err, 'message') && <div>Error message: {err.message}</div>}
                        <Accordion atomic={true}>
                            <AccordionItem title='Toggle detailed error'>
                                <pre>{JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)}</pre>
                            </AccordionItem>
                        </Accordion>
                    </div>
                ),
            })
        } finally {
            if (typeof onRefetch === 'function') {
                onRefetch()
            }
        }
    };

    const handleChargeRefund = async (userId: string, chargeId: string, reasonCode: number) => {
        try {
            setIsLoading(true);
            const response = await dcbApi.refund(userId, 'boku', chargeId, reasonCode)
            setIsLoading(false);
            setTransactionCancellationSent(true);
            Modal.info({
                title: `Your refund request has been submited`,
                okText: 'OK',
                content: (
                    <div>
                        <span>Charge Id:</span> {response.chargeId}<br/>
                        <span>Country:</span> {response.country}<br/>
                        <span>Refund status:</span> {response.refundStatus}<br/>
                        <span>Refund Id:</span> {response.refundId}<br/>
                    </div>
                ),
            })
            //this.setState({ cancellationSent: true })
        } catch (err) {
            setIsLoading(false);
            console.error(err);
            Modal.info({
                title: `Your refund request has failed`,
                okText: 'OK',
                content: (
                    <div>
                        {_.get(err, 'message') && <div>Error message: {err.message}</div>}
                        <Accordion atomic={true}>
                            <AccordionItem title='Toggle detailed error'>
                                <pre>{JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)}</pre>
                            </AccordionItem>
                        </Accordion>
                    </div>
                ),
            })
        } finally {
            if (typeof onRefetch === 'function') {
                onRefetch()
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <Page
            theme='dark' // light|dark
            title='Back to home'
            onLogoClick={navigateHome}
            onTitleClick={navigateHome}
            overlay={(!isLoading && !isLoadingParent) ? undefined :
                <div style={{
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    background: 'rgba(130,131,134,.34)'
                }}>
                    <div style={{
                        textAlign: 'center',
                        position: 'relative',
                        top: '50%',
                        left: '50%',
                        transform: 'translate(-50%,-50%)'
                    }}>
                        <Loader/><br/><br/>
                        <span style={{
                            color: 'white',
                            fontSize: 22,
                            fontFamily: 'Trim',
                            textAlign: 'center'
                        }}>Loading</span>
                    </div>
                </div>}
        >
            <div style={{width: '100%'}}>
                <div
                    style={{
                        textAlign: 'center',
                        marginBottom: 24,
                        fontFamily: 'Trim',
                        fontWeight: 500,
                        fontSize: '26px'
                    }}
                >Subscription statuses for user: {userId}</div>
                <SubscriptionsTable
                    userId={userId}
                    data={subscriptions}
                    cancellationSent={subscriptionCancellationSent}
                    onCancelSubscription={handleSubsctiptionCancel}
                    onViewTransaction={handleViewTransaction}
                />
                <div id="transactions">
                    <div
                        style={{
                            textAlign: 'center',
                            marginTop: 24,
                            marginBottom: 24,
                            fontFamily: 'Trim',
                            fontWeight: 500,
                            fontSize: '26px',
                        }}
                    >
                        {hasTransactions ?
                            `Transactions for user: ${userId}` :
                            <i>This user does not have transactions linked to their subscription</i>}
                    </div>
                    {hasTransactions &&

                    <TransactionsTable
                        userId={userId}
                        data={transactions}
                        cancellationSent={transactionCancellationSent}
                        onRefundCharge={handleChargeRefund}
                    />}
                </div>
            </div>
        </Page>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you add a filtered state inside ResultPage and pass this to TransactionsTable? `handleViewTransaction` will do the filtering depending on subscriptionId. Some "pseudo code":

First, set default with all transactions.

```
const [filteredTransactions, setFilteredTransactions] = useState(transactions);
```

In the handleViewTransactions, do something like:

```
const filteredData = transactions.filter((item) => item.subscriptionId === subscriptionId);
setFilteredTransactions(filteredData);
```

The TransactionsTable component will use the filtered transactions instead:

```
<TransactionsTable
    ...
    data={filteredTransactions}
    ...
/>
```

Comment: Yeah this seems to be a good solution, though I also need to add pagination on transactions :)

Comment: Well, that is another question :). 

If there's a whole lot of transactions and you shouldn't load them all at once:
Let the filtering be done by request to database instead of transactions.filter(...).

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make a component rerender is to have its state or its props change, or an ancestor rerenders. With that in mind, if you want the sibling of a component to rerender when something happens, the best solution is to make the common parent update its state, and pass some value into the sibling.

For your type of scenario, you probably want to hold the selection state in the parent, and pass the value and setter functions down into the children as necessary